# Angular 2: how to deal with Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400. Bad request

Tags: angular

Im Trying to get HTTP GET request using Rest api of my magento.

Below is the angular2 code to achieve the same!.

```
 public ngOnInit() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer x9a278mu7xoh4k0jkj08doc5j4b3ac22');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://10.2.../Mage_ang2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1',options)
        .map(response => console.log(response.json))
        .subscribe((items: Person[]) => {
            console.log('items: ' + items);
            this.people = items;
        }, error => console.log(error));

 }
```

I Get (which im assuming) a CORS issue.

> OPTIONS http://10.2.../Mage_ang2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.2.../Mage_ang2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

I have tried the below steps after workaround in google to fix the same, but unsuccessful.

1) In magento .htaccess file, added

**Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"**

2) In the above angular 2 code added,

**headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');**
...

...

3) Tried changing content-type from application/json in

**let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });**

What am i missing.

Need the proper solution to fix the CORS (from magento2 to angular2) issue.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: I can say that much that this is not an Angular problem, meaning, you don't set the headers on front side. This is a server side issue .

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
> ```

Giving global cross-origin access to Magento (which I understand is a shopping platform) sounds like a very bad idea from a security perspective.

> ```
> headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); ...
> ```

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a **response** header. The server has to send it to the client, not the other way around. Your JS can't give itself permission to access other servers.

> ```
> let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
> ```

Do you have some reason to think that the server was throwing an error because of your default settings?

---

Go back and look at the error message:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Then do a bit of basic research to learn [what a preflight is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Then do a bit more basic research to find out [what HTTP status code 500 means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_error).

So:

- The browser is making an OPTIONS request
- The server is responding with **500 Internal Server Error** (presumably because it hasn't been programmed to respond to an OPTIONS request).

This means that you need to look at your **server side code** (so not your JS at all) and identify *why* it is throwing the 500 error. Your server's error logs will be a good place to start looking.

You need to get the server to correctly respond the the OPTIONS request as per the rules in [the CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

(Alternatively, using the same instructions, you could try to prevent the browser from making a preflight request in the first place, that could be as simple as removing all the attempts to set the CORS response headers on the request where they don't belong).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i understand that Preflight is a request that is sent across a cross site/domain and i need to check if server is configured correctly to get OPTIONS request. For 500 error code, i  checked the server logs, there seems to be no error.... And also which lines do i remove apart from removing headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); to prevent browser for preflight request

Comment: any suggestion on disabling OPTIONS request from browser side

Comment: @Sach — See the last paragraph of my answer.