# C# calling aspnet webapi token endpoint works perfectly on my localhost but givens error on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, openid

```
public static async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> GetTokenForAccess(this User user)
{
        var scheme = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https://" : "http://";
        string baseAddress = $"{scheme}{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority}";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var accept = "application/json";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            string grant_type = "password";
            string body = $"grant_type={grant_type}&username={user.PhoneNumber}&password={user.Password}&grant_access=true";

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{baseAddress}/token")
            {
                Content = new StringContent(body,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            };
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var token = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Token>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.Error))
            {
                return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, token.AccessToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return new Tuple<bool, string>(false, token.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you tell what's the error?

Comment: unsupported_grant_type

Comment: calling the endpoint using postman generates the token but using HttpClient givens error ""unsupported_grant_type"

Comment: Does the value of `grant_type` in c# differ from what you set it to in Postman?

Comment: no, grant_type:password

Comment: Try `FormUrlEncodedContent` instead of `StringContent`

Comment: i have too still the same error, this is the code i used...


                 var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"username", user.PhoneNumber},
                    { "grant_access", "true" },
                    {"grant_type", "password"},
                };
                var tokenResponse = client.PostAsync(baseAddress + "/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(form)).Result;
                var token = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Token>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;

Comment: As an aside, you are in an async method you don't need to block with `.Result`.

Answer (score 0):

You problem should be here:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

Remove the "application/json" because the default implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler only accepts form encoding (i.e. application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and not JSON encoding (application/JSON).

Comment: The accept header asks the server for a particular response format, the request format is defined as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: What i dont get is that it works perfectly on my local machine but is on the server that is given that error

Comment: Have you checked for CORS errors? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036632/8215147) and see if it helps.